# how can i do a javascript substring to retrieve all the values and add it to drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-remoting, lightning

i have a string

```
var str = [Sys[a="Horizon",b="test"],Sys[a="Horizon1",b="test1"],sys[a="Horizon2",b="test2"]]
```

i need to extract the value of all "a" inside str and add it to my drop down list.

**ie , i need a drop down displaying Horizon,Horizon1,Horizon2.. How do i split it and add to my select options in Javascript.**

Currently i have tried the below approach, but i could only retrieve the first value or the last value using "indexOf" and "lastIndexOf".How do i iterate among all the "a=" and it to my options.

Here is my code:

```
<form id="prodEditForm">
    ...
    Product Platform : <select Id="prodPlatform" class="form-control"></select>
    ...                       
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.editButton').on('click', function() {

        var str = [Sys[a="Horizon",b="test"],Sys[a="Horizon1",b="test1"],sys[a="Horizon2",b="test2"]]
        var start = "a=";   
        var end = "b=";
        var arrFrst = str.substring(str.indexOf(start)+start.length+1,str.indexOf(end)-3);
        var arrlast = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(start)+start.length+1,str.lastIndexOf(end)-3);

        var e2=document.getElementById('prodPlatform');
        var o=document.createElement('option');
        o.value=arrFrst ;
        o.text=arrFrst ;
        e2.options.add(o);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am not good in JS, what kind of string is str? looks like some object array. Plus there is no ; at the end.

Comment: are you using selectoption for picklist?

Comment: yes.. it is coming from the object. and i m using Lightining Design system on a VF page. So using <select > <option></option></select> in it for the drop down.